# Python Syntax Error - following the example given and cannot work out where I have gone wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax-error

I am currently doing an apprenticeship in which I am learning to use python 3.

I am going through some exercises, following instructions/walkthroughs provided.

I have started to get the below error when trying to change column names:

```
File "<ipython-input-25-591a166ee92a>", line 5
    'human development index (male)':"hdi_m"
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the code I have used:

```
gender_development.rename(columns={'gdi rank':"gdi_rank",
                                  'gender development index (gdi)':"gdi"
                                  'human development index (male)':"hdi_m"
                                  'life expectancy at birth (female)':"life_expectancy_f"
                                  'life expectancy at birth (male)':"life_expectancy_m"
                                  'expected years of educaton (female)':"expected_education_years_f"
                                  'expected years of education (male)':"expected_education_years_m"
                                  'mean years of education (female)':"mean_education_years_f"
                                  'mean years of education (male)':"mean_education_years_m"
                                  'estimated gross national income per capita (female)':"gross_income_pc_f"
                                  'estimated gross national income per capita (male)':"gross_income_pc_m"
                                  'human development index (female)':"hdi_f"},
                         inplace=True)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need commas at the end of each line in the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing a few commas, which in python dictionaries separate between key-value pairs. Pay attention to the additional commas in the following code:

```
gender_development.rename(columns={'gdi rank': "gdi_rank",
                               'gender development index (gdi)': "gdi",
                               'human development index (male)': "hdi_m",
                               'life expectancy at birth (female)': "life_expectancy_f",
                               'life expectancy at birth (male)': "life_expectancy_m",
                               'expected years of educaton (female)':"expected_education_years_f",
                               'expected years of education (male)': "expected_education_years_m",
                               'mean years of education (female)':"mean_education_years_f",
                               'mean years of education (male)': "mean_education_years_m",
                               'estimated gross national income per capita (female)':"gross_income_pc_f",
                               'estimated gross national income per capita (male)': "gross_income_pc_m",
                               'human development index (female)':"hdi_f"}, inplace = True)
```

All programming langauges are quite sensetive to such syntax errors. Try to pay attention to using the correct structures - with time this will become natural to you.

Comment: Thank you! I keep trying to look for big mistakes and forget about the little bits. I'll get there eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try a linter. The linter will (probably) complain about, line longer than 80 char, under indentation, lack of indent for visual, lack of space after the :, etc.

Clearing all the errors (excepting the missing gender_development) required:

```
gender_development.rename(columns={
    'gdi rank': "gdi_rank",
    'gender development index (gdi)': "gdi",
    'human development index (male)': "hdi_m",
    'life expectancy at birth (female)': "life_expectancy_f",
    'life expectancy at birth (male)': "life_expectancy_m",
    'expected years of educaton (female)': "expected_education_years_f",
    'expected years of education (male)': "expected_education_years_m",
    'mean years of education (female)': "mean_education_years_f",
    'mean years of education (male)': "mean_education_years_m",
    'estimated gross national income per capita (female)': "gross_income_pc_f",
    'estimated gross national income per capita (male)': "gross_income_pc_m",
    'human development index (female)': "hdi_f"
}, inplace=True)
```